# Models having the same standard system

Tags: logic, set-theory

In the paper "[A natural model of the multiverse axioms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4450)", Gitman and Hamkins give the following construction:

Given a countable computably saturated model of ZFC, $M$,  they show that there is an $N\in M$ which satisfies $Th(M)$ and $M$ thinks that $N$ is $\omega$-nonstandard.

Then they claim that "since $\omega^M$ is an initial segment of $\omega^N$ and $M$ is $\omega$-nonstandard, it follows that $M$ and $N$ have the same standard system."

First, I want to make sure I understand why $\omega^M$ is an initial segment of $\omega^N$: since $M$ thinks of itself as standard, and of $N$ as non-standard, $M\vDash\forall n<\omega (n\in\omega^N)$, so by looking from the outside we get $\forall n<\omega^M (n\in\omega^N)$. Is that right?

Second, and more importantly, I don't understand why it follows that they have the same standard system. Is it something immediate that I miss, or a well-known result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First, I want to make sure I understand why $\omega^M$ is an initial segment of $\omega^N$: since $M$ thinks of itself as standard, and of $N$ as non-standard, $M\vDash\forall n<\omega (n\in\omega^N)$, so by looking from the outside we get $\forall n<\omega^M (n\in\omega^N)$. Is that right?

That's exactly right.

> Second, and more importantly, I don't understand why it follows that they have the same standard system. Is it something immediate that I miss, or a well-known result?

Let $n\in \omega^M$ be nonstandard.  Then for any $a\in M$, $a\cap \omega=(a\cap n)\cap\omega$, so to determine the standard system of $M$, we can restrict to just subsets of $n$.  But $M$ thinks $n$ is finite, so $M$ thinks $N$ must contain all subsets of $n$.  So the entire standard system of $M$ must be in the standard system of $N$.  Conversely, if $a$ is an element of $N$, then $a\cap\omega^M\in M$ and this has same intersection with the true $\omega$ as $a$, so the standard system of $N$ is contained in the standard system of $M$.

(Here I am abusing notation slightly and identifying $\omega$ with the canonical initial segment of $\omega^M$ which is isomorphic to it and $\omega^M$ with the canonical initial segment of $\omega^N$ which is isomorphic to it.  Since the element relation of $M$ is not actually $\in$ and the element relation of $N$ is not actually the element relation of $M$, things like "$a\cap \omega$" or "$a\cap\omega^M$" which I wrote don't make sense literally.)

---

Actually, more strongly, you can prove that if $M$ and $N$ are arbitrary $\omega$-nonstandard models of ZFC (so we're not assuming $N\in M$) and $\omega^M$ is isomorphic to an initial segment of $\omega^N$ over the language of arithmetic, then $M$ and $N$ have the same standard systems.  To prove this, let $m\in\omega^M$ be any nonstandard element.  Note that for any $a\in M$, $M$ thinks $a\cap m$ is a finite set.  It follows that $M$ can encode the set $a\cap m$ with an element of $\omega^M$, by the usual method of encoding finite sets of natural numbers in arithmetic.  Identifying $\omega^M$ with its isomorphic initial segment of $\omega^N$, this element will also encode the set $a\cap m$ in $\omega^N$, so $a\cap m$ must also be a set in $N$.  It follows that the standard system of $M$ is contained in the standard system of $N$.  The converse can be proved the same way, since the natural number encoding a subset of $m$ in $N$ will still be an element of the initial segment $\omega^M$.

Comment: It seems that you are using only the fact that $M$ is nonstandard and thinks that $N$ contains at least all of it's $\omega$, so it would work also if $N$ is not thought by $M$ to be nonstandard?

Comment: Yes, this would work even if $M$ thinks $N$ is standard.

Comment: And could you add why is the standard system of N contained in that of M? I mean, since M isn't necessarily transitive (or is it?) a set in N that codes some standard set may not be in M. And it is not assumed that N is an elementary substructure of M, just elementary equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! But still, why is $a\cap\omega^M\in M$ if $M$ doesn't recognise $a$?

Comment: That's just by Separation in $M$: $M$ thinks that there exists a subset of $\omega$ consisting of exactly those natural numbers $n$ such that $N\vDash n\in a$.

Comment: But how does $M$ know what $N$ thinks of $a$ if $M$ doesn't know $a$? If $a$ is not in $M$ then $N\vDash n\in a$ is not a formula with parameters in $M$...

Comment: The structure $N$ is a set in $M$!  So $M$ knows everything about $N$.

Comment: What do you mean "knows everything"? If e.g.  I take $M$ to be a countable elementary substructure of some $H(\theta)$ such that $\omega_1\in M$. So $M$ surely does not know all the elements of $\omega_1$.

Comment: I think you're confused about what everything means here: $a$ _is_ an element of $M$.  When we refer to "elements" of $N$, we mean elements $a\in M$ such that $a\in^M N$.  When we think of $N$ as a structure in the language of set theory, the underlying set of this structure is really $\{a\in M:a\in^M N\}$, not the literal set $N$ itself.  The literal set $N$ could be any set at all, since $\in^M$ may be totally unrelated to the true $\in$ relation.

Comment: A-ha, I see. Indeed I did not understand it this way, thanks. I see now that this is hidden in the way they identify $N$ - it is constructed using the completeness theorem in $M$, so indeed everything there is an element of $M$.

Comment: Could you please add this clarification to your answer? Or if you prefer - I can do it.

Comment: You can add it--I'm not sure exactly what you want added.

Comment: Ok I read it again and in fact it is quite clear after I realized my confusion. I just made a cosmetic change from $a\in N$ to $a$ is an element of $N$ to avoid the impression that it is the actual membership relation.

Comment: A question - are you actually using the fact that $\omega^M$ is an initial segment of $\omega^N$? In the paper they state it a few times as the reason $M$ and $N$ has the same standard system (with the fact they are nonstandard), but It doesn't seem like you use it directly.

Comment: Hmmm, that's true.  I've added another argument that uses only that fact.